# Output Each Word In A Sentence Using Hash/List

Tags: java

I have a program where I have a sentence inputted. The sentence is split up into words using regEx/a split method. The words are stored in an Array called wordsInLine and my job is to add those words to an ArrayList called WordList.

If we find a match between WordList and wordsInLine we move on to the next word and so on and so forth. My job is to output each word.

Expected input = The score of the game is five to five.

Expected output:

Word: The

Word: Score

Word: Of

Word: The

So on and so forth

Main Class:

```
package proj1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Proj1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int lineWord = 0, listWord = 0;

    String inputLine = "The score of the game is five to five";
    String regEx = "(, *)|(: *)|\\s";
    String[] wordsInLine;

    ArrayList<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();

    wordsInLine = inputLine.split(regEx);

    if (wordList.isEmpty())
      System.out.println("Empty List");



  }
}
```

Word Class:

```
package proj1;

class Word {   

  String Word;
  int timesWordIsRepeated;

  public Word (String words, int count) {
    words = Word;     
  }

  public String getWord() {
    return Word;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    String theString = String.format("Word :",Word );
    return theString;
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you can explain exactly (and give examples of) the output you expect for specific inputs. (You have explained your planned approach to solving the problem, but what is the problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps there is a better way to solve it.)

Comment: Sorry. The output I'm looking for is just this:

Word: The
Word: Score
Word: Of
Word: The
Word: Game
Word: Is
Word: Five
Word: To
Word: Five

Comment: I'm confused what that means. What I'm looking for are concrete examples of: inputs and expected outputs. Can you modify the original question to add these examples.

Comment: Input = The score of the game is five to five.

The output would just be the following

Word: The
         Word: Score



Basically it takes the input which is a sentence and then outputs "Word" + the first word of the sentence. Then "Word" + the second word of the sentence. Then "Word" + the third word of the sentence and so on/so forth. 

Sorry If I'm not explaining it well.

Comment: I'll modify the question, one second.

Comment: So there's no counting?

Comment: There is counting, basically I just have to count the amount of times the word is said in the sentence. So every word is in the sentence once, except 5 which is in the sentence twice.

I know how to do the Counter method though...just can't get the words to be outputted.

I edited out the times counted part of the question to lessen confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate like this to obtain each word:

```
String inputLine = "The score of the game is five to five";
for (String word : inputLine.split(" ")) {
    System.out.println("Word: " + word);
}
```

Prints:

```
Word: The
Word: score
Word: of
Word: the
Word: game
Word: is
Word: five
Word: to
Word: five
```

Comment: That works, and that seems to me like it's the easiest solution. However I have to use a getter method and compare the array with the ArrayList and if the word is in both the Array and ArrayList its a match and is outputted.

I do appreciate the help though :)

Comment: What does this mean? What is the point of comparing the array and the list? Wouldn't you just copy all the words in to the list? Please clarify what the purpose of the list is.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` can better help you to count word then `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

    String inputLine = "The score of the game is five to five";
    String regEx = "(, *)|(: *)|(\\? *)|(; *)|(! *)|( *\\( *)|(\\) *)|\\s";
    String[] wordsInLine;

    Map<String, Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    wordsInLine = inputLine.split(regEx);

    for (String lineWord : wordsInLine) {
        Integer count = wordMap.get(lineWord);
        if (count == null) {
            wordMap.put(lineWord, 1);
        } else {
            wordMap.put(lineWord, (count + 1));
        }
    }

    if (wordMap.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No entry found");
    } else {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordMap.entrySet()) {
            // you can create Word pojo here if you want new Word(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()) and add to some list
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

With `ArrayList`

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

        String inputLine = "The score of the game is five to five";
        String regEx = "(, *)|(: *)|(\\? *)|(; *)|(! *)|( *\\( *)|(\\) *)|\\s";
        String[] wordsInLine;

        ArrayList<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();

        wordsInLine = inputLine.split(regEx);

        for (String lineWord : wordsInLine) {
            boolean wordFound = false;
            for (Word word : wordList) {
                if (word.getWord().equals(lineWord)) {
                    wordFound = true;
                    word.setCount(word.getCount() + 1);
                }
            }
            if (!wordFound) {
                wordList.add(new Word(lineWord, 1));
            }
        }
        if (wordList.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty List");
        } else {
            for (Word word : wordList) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }

    }

    static class Word {

        String word;
        int count;

        public Word(String word, int count) {
            this.word = word;
            this.count = count;
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Word [word=" + word + ", count=" + count + "]";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Is there any way to do this using an ArrayList though? Just curious.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would solve your problem:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new LinkedHashMap<>();

String inputLine = "The score of the game is five to five";
for (String word : inputLine.split(" ")) {
    int count = 1;
    if (wordCounts.containsKey(word)) {
        count += wordCounts.get(word);
    }
    wordCounts.put(word, count);
}

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: wordCounts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Word: " + entry.getKey() + " (" + entry.getValue() + ")");
}
```

Prints:

```
Word: The (1)
Word: score (1)
Word: of (1)
Word: the (1)
Word: game (1)
Word: is (1)
Word: five (2)
Word: to (1)
```

To use an `ArrayList` you can do this:

```
List<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();

String inputLine = "The score of the game is five to five";

outerLoop:
for (String s : inputLine.split(" ")) {
    for (Word existingWord : words) {
        if (existingWord.value.equals(s)) {
            existingWord.count++;
            continue outerLoop;
        }
    }
    words.add(new Word(s));
}

for (Word word : words) {
    System.out.println("Word: " + word.value + " (" + word.count + ")");
}
```

With this class too:

```
class Word {
    final String value;
    int count = 1;

    public Word(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
Word: The (1)
Word: score (1)
Word: of (1)
Word: the (1)
Word: game (1)
Word: is (1)
Word: five (2)
Word: to (1)
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. Is there any way to do this with an ArrayList or can you only do it with Map/Hash? 

Doesn't matter either way, I'm just curious.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Sadly, I think I'm supposed to iterate over the list each time because it is an ArrayList project, but this is just so much simpler.

Comment: I've added an ArrayList version, but it's inefficient compared to a Map.